# With KStream implementation, should I set ProducerConfig or StreamsConfig settings?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have a KStream implementation and I see that both ProducerConfig and StreamsConfig have similar settings such as REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG.

Should I set both?
If not, which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both evaluate to the same thing (along with the ConsumerConfig property). If you set both, the later one overwrites the first since that's how Java Maps & Properties work.

Its generally easier to read your code if you stick with StreamsConfig constants when writing Kafka Streams jobs

Comment: I am particularly interested in the retry setting for which in my kafka-steams 1.0.0 version does not exist (for StreamsConfig). Will setting the ProducerConfig have the same result?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm just pointing out that the two properties you mentioned are the exact same, and using either one has no affect on the end results of your code

Comment: Also check out the docs: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#kafka-consumers-producer-and-admin-client-configuration-parameters